# Flask, Join two models with foreign key

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

my two models are

```
class Users (db.Model):
    UserId = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    UserName = db.Column(db.String(25),nullable=False, unique=True)
    Email = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False,unique=True)
    plan = db.relationship(
        'Messages',
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('language'),
        cascade="all,delete"
    )

class Messages (db.Model):
    MessageId = db.Column(db.INTEGER,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    SenderId = db.Column(db.INTEGER,db.ForeignKey('Users.UserId'),nullable=False)
    language = db.Column(db.Enum('de', 'en'), nullable=False)
```

Now, My view looks like:

```
def premium():
    usr_obj = models.Users.query.join(models.Messages)\
        .order_by(models.Users.UserId.desc())

    return render_template('user_plan.html', user=usr_obj)
```

My user_html is like:

```
{% for a in user %}
            {{ a.UserName }} </br> {{ a.SenderID }} </br>
        {% endfor %}
```

It is giving me only value of {{ a.UserName }} and not of {{ a.SenderID }}, why??

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your models? `relationship` should refer to `Messages` not `Message`, right?

Comment: No, there is no typo, in code, I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

if you want only senderId and UserName from this join,you can try this:

```
     obj= Users.query.with_entities(Users.UserName,Messages.SenderId
             ).join(Messages,Messages.SenderId==Users.UserId
             ).order_by(Users.UserId.desc()
             ).all()
```

explanation:- 
   we are applying join on Messages.SenderId and Users.UserId

with_entities: it means we only want UserName, SenderId from this join.

you can use for loop to access UserName and SenderId from this join.
like this:

```
    for o in obj:
      print o.UserName,o.SenderId
```

i hope this is solution of your problem.Use it according to your problem case.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me error: AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'

Answer (score 0):

One can use:

```
{% for a in user %}
        {{ a.UserName }} </br> {{ a.plan[g.current_lang].SenderID }} </br>
    {% endfor %}
```